# Has anyone got a fix for the GLImageProcessing sample for the iPad simulator?

Tags: opengl-es, ios-simulator, ios

This is sample code from the Apple and yet does not work correctly on the iPad simulator. I don't have an I've been trying to get it to work correctly on the iPad simulator. The image is offset to approx the center of the screen, but not exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. When using "Upgrade current target for iPad" the .xmb places the EAGLView at aprox (270,270). Setting it at (0,0) solves the problem.

Comment: An even better solution is to create a new OpenGL project from the New Project menu and use that as a basis. The template project handles changes in view size.